# List items after category choice in RecyclerView (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview displaying my categories as a list and a ClickListener for for each item.
My plan is to show the user a list of items corresponding to the choosen category.
Is there an other way than to create an activity+RecyclerView-adapter for each categorie?

Edit:

Categories are in fact Categories, so "herb", "side dishes", etc..
Currently its a data class consisting of "name" and "image"

I have the Activity "Ingredients" and the correspoding Adapter "IngAdapter".
The XML for this activity consists of the Recyclerview showing the categories.

The Items for every Categorie will be stored in a room, that has not been created yet.

Comment: you should add some code to let us see what category means. Assuming category is a data class, normally you make 1 activity/fragment, 1 recyclerview inside this view and 1 adapter. Now if you want to show a list of items from that category (master-detail), you'll probably need another view, recyclerview and adapter but you can re use it between the items from your different categories

Comment: I made an edit regarding more information. If I understand correctly you mean I can create a new Activity/Adapter/Recylcerview for the items and reuse it. Then  I would add the start of the new Activity (Ingredients) in the ClickListener of the Master-Activity. But how do I change the Items corresponding to the clicked category?

Comment: That's correct. You need to pass to the ingredients activity the list of items you want to display, which will vary according to the category you selected. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application) shows you how to pass data from one activity to another. You should pass the whole list to the ingredients activity